# SimpleXMLElement to modify root tag

Tags: php, attributes, simplexml

Good day,

I am having trouble modifying XML using SimpleXMLElement in PHP.

My XML structure is as below:

```
<chart caption='NULL' shownames='1' showvalues='0' decimals='2' numberPrefix='$' useRoundEdges='0' legendBorderAlpha='0' bgColor='FFFFFF' canvasBorderColor='A5A5A5' canvasBorderThickness='1' showToolTip='1'>
...
</chart>
```

How can I modify the attributes() on the root tag using SimpleXMLElement?

Thank you!

EDIT:
Hmm... I found a way but I dont believe its very clean. I added a `<root><chart ...>...</chart></root>` tag wraping my XML data. And I finally added `str_replace(array("<root>", "</root>"), "", $_RenderedXML->asXML())` to my code. Any idea that is.. "cleaner"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TO change the "shownames" attribute to (String) "2"

```
<?

$dom = simplexml_load_string("<chart caption='NULL' shownames='1' showvalues='0' decimals='2' numberPrefix='$' useRoundEdges='0' legendBorderAlpha='0' bgColor='FFFFFF' canvasBorderColor='A5A5A5' canvasBorderThickness='1' showToolTip='1'></chart>");
$dom['shownames'] = '2';
var_dump($dom);
```

Comment: I dont know why this have been downvoted. But this work for me. I believe it was one technique I forgot to try.

Comment: Maybe because i had the sample XML inline with the code. which is kinda frowned upon. But i was too lazy to use DOMDocument to build up the XML. I never meant for this to be the actual code, but just enough to teach you how to do it so  you can integrate into your code. Glad it helped :)